# build error UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 2 errors

Tags: unity-game-engine

The following error occurs when unity builds with Android phone.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2d4U.png)

The first time you don't set anything up, the build will succeed.

However, after downloading the ar foundation and arcore xr plugin package, the following error occurs.

What's the reason?

Comment: Look at the first error. It says it all

Answer (score 0):

As the error at the top says, you have the Vulkan graphics API enabled and it’s not supported by ARCore. Go into Player Settings > Android and remove Vulkan from the list of graphics APIs. (If it’s not listed because Graphics API is set to Auto you’ll need to disable Auto I guess).

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to file>build settings>player settings>other settings> and delete all Graphic Apis that are deprecated and delete vulkan, that seems to work just fine for me.